# Illustrator Opacity masks not recognised in InDesign

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, transparency

I am trying to **place an .ai file containing Opacity Masks into InDesign.** 
However, in InDesign the Opacity Masks are not displayed as intended. Any ideas or checkboxes I might have missed?

**Here's the object in Illustrator:** 
*(its a simple red square with the "stamp border" outline that is clipped via opacity mask)*

[image: the Illustrator view]

**And this is what the placed .ai file looks like in InDesign:**

[image: the InDesign view]

---

I know that there are ways of constructing the stamp shape in Illustrator without using Opacity Masks – I would prefer to keep the edges live though, to be able to edit the "cutout"-radius.

---

Any pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of copy pasting, try saving the AI file, and then place it in InDesign.

Comment: thank you for the reply @BillyKerr, I am actually placing the file. (as copy-pasting is not an option in this scenario since the stamps will be filled with detailed graphic elements)

Comment: in your question it says "And this is what the pasted .ai file looks like".

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. corrected.

Comment: If you export the .indd as a .pdf or .jpg, does the effect show up again? It might just be that InDesign's preview function can't handle the mask but it exports it properly.

Comment: @Vincent - thank you so much! You are right, it does export properly it's the internal InDesign Preview function that doesn't support the Opacity Masks. If you add your comment as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Have you saved the file aa .eps (10 or cs..) and see if indesign recognizes the opacity mask?

Comment: Did you try to change the preview quality to 'high quality preview'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably due to InDesign's preview function for vector files being shoddy rather than an error in your file. Try and export a .pdf or .jpg from your InDesign file and see whether the effect shows up in there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found that using a linked file for the mask does not work. However if you embed the mask image in the the AI file, itt works OK, InDesign recocnizes the mask.