# Illustrator vector objects lose their curves when imported into InDesign

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, vector, workflow

I am having a new issue with **Illustrator 2020** and **InDesign 2020** compatibility.

If I drag-and-drop `.ai` files into an **InDesign** Artboard (or Place them), their curves become edgy. However, if I copy them in **Illustrator** and paste them in **InDesign**, the curves remain smooth.

[image]

To make the issue more visible, here is an animation switching back and forth the two shapes:

[image]

There are no options in **InDesign** corresponding to the smoothness of placed vector files:

[image]

### Why are these vector shapes becoming less smooth when imported in **InDesign**?

Comment: See this [possibly related question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/137362/illustrator-opacity-masks-not-recognised-in-indesign/137369#137369).

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem of Bezier flatness settings in the shapes selected....check your AICB (Adobe Illustrator Clip Board) settings.....set to copy data as pdf

Comment: But the OP has problems *placing* files, not copy/pasting.